# How to read missing typeface name in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

How can i read a full name of the missing font:

[image]

**UPDATE FOR Kevin Sina**

Here's the window you were talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Use Missing Font Window**

1. Click on the **"Notifications"** button at the top right side of the window
2. Click on **"Missing Fonts"**
   [image: Missing Fonts button]
3. You can see the list of missing fonts and their full name here
   [image: Missing Fonts]

**Method 2: Use Third-party Plugin**

1. Download **Fontily** Plugin from [here](https://github.com/partyka1/Fontily?ref=thesketchapphub)
2. Unzip and install the plugin
3. Click on **Plugins** -> **Fontily** -> **"Find & Replace Fonts"** or **"List fonts used"**
   [image: menu]
4. in both windows you can find the full name of the fonts. The missing fonts are red.
   [image: fonts]
   [image: fonts]

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot, font name won't fit the sketch window with missing fonts, hence i can only guess what is this, lol. Is there any way to increase width of "missing fonts" window?

Comment: The screenshot you put here is in the right sidebar. In the right sidebar, it is not possible, but if you open the missing font dialog in the way I've mentioned, you can increase the width of the window as much as you want (second image)

Comment: I've added a screenshot, it doesn't matter, i still can't see the full name, also i can't increase width of this window, only height.

Comment: It is weird because I can change the width of the window. however, I tried to find another solution. you can install a plugin to manage the fonts you are using. I've updated the answer.